# How "ugly" can a derivative get?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

There are plenty of examples of differentiable functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with derivatives that are not everywhere continuous. However, as stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108731/nowhere-continuous-real-valued-function-which-has-an-antiderivative), it is impossible for the derivative to be nowhere continuous. In *general*, can anything be said about exactly how "ugly" a derivative can get?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be?rq=1).

Comment: There is the question: What is the measure of the "ugliness" of the derivative? Is it how many places it is not continuous?